# Why `return()` & `onsubmit()` do not work while creating a login form to welcome page in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

While creating login form to welcome page in HTML, CSS, js the problem faced is the return statement is not working.

**create code for HTML inbuilt javascript.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>LOGIN FORM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
 <div class="loginbox">
 <img src="C:\Users\Hp\Pictures\Camera Roll\avatar2.png" class="avatar">
 <h1>Login Here</h1><br>
  <form action="loginbox.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
   <div>
   <p>user name</p>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter User name" id="user name">
   </div><br>
   <div>
   <p>password</p>
   <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter password" id="password">
   </div><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="login"><br>
   <a href="#">Lost your pasword??</a><br>
   <a href="#">don't have an account??</a>
  </form>
 </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var attempt = 3;
 function validate()
 {
        var user name= document.getElementById("user name").value;
        var password= document.getElementById("password").Value;

  if(user name.value=="dr" && password.value=="8428")
  {      
             
            return true;
        }
  else{
   attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
            alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
            // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
            if( attempt == 0){
            document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
  }
 }
 </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Using return false statement it should stop entering into welcome page, but in this code it's not working, it goes to next page.

Tried that `onsubmit="return false; validate();"` while using this code entire block gets stop & won't enter to welcome page.

Comment: Did you check for errors in your browser's"s Console? Or try to step through the code with the debugger?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that id was missing in submit, you have to declare id in the input that has type submit. Secondly, the logic was incorrect when you validate the form, return statement was missing in the else part when the attempt was not equal to zero.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>LOGIN FORM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
var attempt =3;
function validateForm() {

      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

      if (username == "dr" && password == "8428") {

        return true;
      } else {
         attempt--;// Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt!");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
        
          document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
         return false;
        }
        
        return false;
      }
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loginbox">
    
    <h1>Login Here</h1><br>
    <form action="/loginbox.html" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <div>
        <p>user name</p>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter User name" id="username">
      </div><br>
      <div>
        <p>password</p>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="password">
      </div><br>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="login"><br>
      <a href="#">Lost your pasword??</a><br>
      <a href="#">don't have an account??</a>
    </form>
  </div>

 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll avoid downvotes if you take the time to explain your answer

Comment: Hey @ADyson, thanks for the guidelines, I will keep this in mid. :)

Comment: hello @PratyushSwain, thanks for your answer, it's working for me and I will take it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are using spaces in your id attribute which is incorrect, the id attribute must not have anykind of spaces. Plus, you are missing id="submit" on the submit button. In your code the JS is unable to execute this line

```
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
```

Because the submit button doesn't have any ID.
 Below has the errors fixed. This should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>LOGIN FORM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="C:\Users\Hp\Pictures\Camera Roll\avatar2.png" class="avatar">
    <h1>Login Here</h1><br>
        <form action="loginbox.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <div>
            <p>user name</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter User name" id="username">
            </div><br>
            <div>
            <p>password</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter password" id="password">
            </div><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="login" id="submit"><br>
            <a href="#">Lost your pasword??</a><br>
            <a href="#">don't have an account??</a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var attempt = 3;
    function validate()
    {
        var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password= document.getElementById("password").Value;

        if(username == "dr" && password == "8428")
        {      

            return true;
        }
        else{
            attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
            alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
            // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
            if( attempt == 0){
            document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll avoid downvotes if you take the time to explain your answer

Comment: @Quentin
"HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters."
Source : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class
This will help you :)